# C++ dynamic array allocation and strange use of memset

Tags: c++, pointers

I recently ran into this code in C++:

```
int m=5;
int n=4;
int *realfoo = new int[m+n+3];
int *foo;
foo = realfoo + n + 1;
memset(realfoo, -1, (m+n+2)*sizeof(int));
```

Only the variable "foo" is used in the rest of the code, "realfoo" is never used (just freed at the very end).
I can't understand what that means.
What kind of operation is `foo = realfoo + n + 1;`? How is it possible to assign an array plus an int?
The memset sets every value of "realfoo" to -1. How does this affect "foo"?

**EDIT**
Since many have asked for the entire code. Here it is:

```
int Wu_Alg(char *A, char *B, int m, int n)
{
   int *realfp = new int[m+n+3];
   int *fp, p, delta;
   fp = realfp + n + 1;
   memset(realfp, -1, (m+n+2)*sizeof(int));
   delta = n - m;
   p = -1;
   
   while(fp[delta] != n){
      p=p+1;
      for(int k = -p; k <= delta-1; k++){
         fp[k]=snake(A, B, m, n, k, Max(fp[k-1]+1, fp[k+1]));          
      }
      for(int k = delta+p; k >= delta+1; k--){
         fp[k] = snake(A, B, m, n, k, Max(fp[k-1]+1, fp[k+1]));        
      }
      fp[delta] = snake(A, B, m, n, delta, Max(fp[delta-1]+1, fp[delta+1]));
   }
   delete [] realfp;
   return delta+2*p;
}
int snake(char *A, char *B, int m, int n, int k, int j)
{
   int i=j-k;
   while(i < m && j < n && A[i+1] == B[j+1]){
      i++;
      j++;
   }
   return j;
}
```

Source: [http://par.cse.nsysu.edu.tw/~lcs/Wu%20Algorithm.php](http://par.cse.nsysu.edu.tw/%7Elcs/Wu%20Algorithm.php)
The algorithm is: https://publications.mpi-cbg.de/Wu_1990_6334.pdf

Comment: `new` is not part of C, you must be using C++

Comment: They are not "arrays", they are pointers - you are changing what the *pointer* `foo` points to

Comment: "*"realfoo" is never used*" But you wrote `memset(realfoo, ...` right after that.

Comment: If anything `foo` isn't used, `realfoo` is used -- twice in the above code.

Comment: `foo` points to the 6th `int` inside of the block allocated for `realfoo`.

Comment: `realfoo` is never use in the **rest** of the code. Just `foo` is used. Why declaring `realfoo`? Why not declare just foo?

Comment: So now `foo` points into the middle of the `realfoo` array.  Nothing wrong with that.  Sometimes it's convenient if you want to be able to use negative indices: `foo[-n-1], foo[-n], ..., foo[-1], foo[0], foo[1], ..., foo[m+1]` are all valid.

Comment: @john you are asking for *speculation* here -- without the *rest* of the code or some more context, all we can do is guess as to what this code is intended for.

Comment: No reason can be given without seeing [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could be that the code uses the first 5 `int` in the block for metadata of some type -- who knows -- but we could tell with a MCVE...

Comment: @John "*never use in the rest of the code ... why*" No one can guess why or how it's used unless you post *that* code. "*Why not declare just foo*" You need a pointer to the beginning of the array in order to allocate and free it.

Comment: `"realfoo" to -1. How does this affect "foo"?` -- depends, if your hardware uses twos-complement, it will have the effect of setting bits 1-31 to `1` for each `int`.

Comment: @NateEldredge You're totally right! I didn't think that, thank you! Now I understand..

Comment: If you use the optimizer (`-O3` in `g++` and `clang++`) you'll find what effect all the code has. Spoiler alert:
`main:
   xor eax, eax
   ret`

(that is, none)  - So, as asked for by @DavidC.Rankin above: Make a [mre]. Please.

Comment: `foo = realfoo + n + 1` is equivalent to `foo = &realfoo[n+1]`.   So it treats `realfoo` as an array, and causes `foo` to point at its `n+1`th element.   This means `foo[i]` is an alias for `realfoo[i + n+1]`.   This also means that `foo` can have negative indices e.g.  `foo[-n-1]` is an alias `realfoo[0]`.   It is curious that the `memset()` call sets `m+n+2` elements of `realfoo`, and leaves `realfoo[m+n+2]` (which is part of the allocated block) uninitialised - a consequence is that, if `realfoo[m+n+2]` is not initialised, accessing its value gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter `int *foo;
foo = realfoo + n + 1;` is vapor trail. No effect. The only thing I can see is a program `memset`:ing short, and leaking memory.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - I wouldn't agree it is a "vapor trail".  The OP mentioned there is subsequent code that uses `foo` only, and was seeking to understand how usage of `foo` related to `realfoo`.    I realise that compilers are likely to optimise things out anyway, but knowing that doesn't help someone understand what is going on.

Comment: @Peter What OP says and presents are probably different things. `foo` isn't used. The pointer addition isn't even out of bounds. It's a no-op - and _not_ UB. It's just something that'll be discarded by any sane compiler.

Comment: @Peter Thank you Peter, you perfectly understood what I was trying to say. I posted the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
foo = realfoo + n + 1;
```

Assigns `foo` to point to element `n + 1` of `realfoo`.  Using array indexing / pointer arithmetic equivalency, it's the same as:

```
foo = &realfoo[n + 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

`memset` is not setting the value to -1. It is used to every byte to -1
You should create a loop to iterate every element to assign correctly.

```
for(size_t i= 0; i< m+n+3; i++){
    realfoo[i] = -1;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this -- this approach *also* initializes, why use this over `memset`?

Comment: @costaparas: The `memset` approach relies on the assumption that the `int` `-1` is represented internally as repeated bytes of `-1`, which is not guaranteed to be true on all platforms (though it is true on many common ones).

Comment: @nate thanks forgot about that, normally `memset` is used for char arrays not for int arrays. But since this is C++ and not C, `std::fill_n` would be the preferred method here.

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of operation is foo = realfoo + n + 1;?

This is an assignment operation. The left hand operand, the variable `foo`, is assigned a new value. The right hand operand `realfoo + n + 1` provides that value.

> How is it possible to assign an array plus an int?

Because the array decays to a pointer.

> The memset sets every value of "realfoo" to -1.

Not quite. All except the last value is set. The last one is left uninitialised.

Note that technically each byte is set to -1. If the system uses one's complement representation of signed integers, then the value of the resulting integer will not be -1 (it would be -16'843'009 assuming a 32 bit integer and 8 bit byte).

> How does this affect "foo"?

`foo` itself is not affected. But `foo` points to an object that is affected.

Bonus advice: The example program leaks memory. I recommend avoiding owning bare pointers.